# Creating a meme and storing into local

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I'm trying to create a meme image in the browser by getting input from the user.

The user should also able to download the image after the creation of the meme.

The code is given below, in which the download/save button is not working

```js
function textChangeListener(evt) {
  var id = evt.target.id;
  var text = evt.target.value;

  if (id == "topLineText") {
    window.topLineText = text;
  } else {
    window.bottomLineText = text;
  }

  redrawMeme(window.imageSrc, window.topLineText, window.bottomLineText);
}
//------
function redrawMeme(image, topLine, bottomLine) {
  // Get Canvas2DContext
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (image != null)
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // clear previous
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  if (image != null)
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Text attributes
  ctx.font = '30pt Impact';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

  if (topLine != null) {
    ctx.fillText(topLine, canvas.width / 2, 40);
    ctx.strokeText(topLine, canvas.width / 2, 40);
  }

  if (bottomLine != null) {
    ctx.fillText(bottomLine, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 20);
    ctx.strokeText(bottomLine, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 20);
  }
}

function saveFile() {

  window.open(document.querySelector('canvas').toDataURL());
}
//--------

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  //make canvas
  var canvasWidth = 500;
  var canvasHeight = 500;
  var file = evt.target.files[0];

  //image upload
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(fileObject) {
    var data = fileObject.target.result;

    // Create an image object
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {

      window.imageSrc = this;
      redrawMeme(window.imageSrc, null, null);
    }

    // Set image data to background image.
    image.src = data;
    console.log(fileObject.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
window.imageSRC = null;
window.topLineText = "";
window.bottomLineText = "";
window.imageSRC = null;
window.topLineText = null;
window.bottomLineText = null;

var file = document.querySelector("#file");
file.onchange = handleFileSelect;

var input1 = document.getElementById('topLineText');
var input2 = document.getElementById('bottomLineText');
input1.oninput = textChangeListener;
input2.oninput = textChangeListener;
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', saveFile, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html2canvas</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>CREATE YOUR OWN MEME</h1>
    <p>Upload an image, type in some lines and save</p>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
  </div>
  <div id="image-container">
    <canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="inputs">
      <br/>
      <input id="topLineText" type="text" placeholder="TOP LINE"><br/>
      <br/>
      <input id="bottomLineText" type="text" placeholder="BOTTOM LINE"><br/>
      <button id="saveBtn" onclick="saveFile()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

i think there should be some fix in saveFile(), can anyone help me to fix this code?
iam trying to do this without angular support

Comment: Why does `saveFile` open a window (which is most likely blocked by the browser)? Use the Blob API instead, e.g. with the [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method and a dynamically added `<a download>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems opening the canvas data url in the new window does not works. Better way to download the image is create a link tag and assign your canvas url then open the link
try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gd3a7hLn/

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'filename.png';
link.href = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL()
link.click();
```